# django post returning token not post data

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm making a post from a webpage that is generated dynamically from Django DB content. The data is put into a combo box and is supposed to send the customer id back to Django so I can parse some more queries with it and then display only the customers data that was selected.

However instead of retruning my post data it returns the csrf token instead of the posted data.

```
<form method='post' action='' id='customers'>
{% csrf_token %}
        <select>
        {% for item in customer %}
        <option value={{ item.customer_id }} name='customer_id'>{{ item.customer_name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type = 'submit' value='Edit'>
        </select>
{{ post }}
{{post.customer_id}} #doesnt work either.
```

this is what it returns:

```
<QueryDict: {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'CpzKrwmZsmfiiNHngNWDFSNxqUoBykYO']}>
```

def portal(request):

```
customers = Customer.objects.all()

if request.method == 'POST':
   vm_groups = Vm_group.objects.all()
   vms = Vm.objects.all()
   selected_customer = request.POST.copy()
   #selected_customer_id = selected_customer['customer_id']

   post = selected_customer
   context = Context({'customer': customers, 'vm_groups':vm_groups, 'vms':vms, 'post':post, 
                                               })

   return render(request, 'portal.html', context)

else:
   context = Context({'customer': customers,})
   return render(request, 'portal.html', context)
```

Also how would I get just the customer_id from the returned data once it works correctly?

```
selected_customer = request.POST.copy()
selected_customer_id = selected_customer['customer_id']
```

Like so?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `name` attribute on the `select` element, not the `option`.

But you should probably be using Django's forms framework, anyway.

Comment: Thanks ok so im returning the correct id number now I wrote an if statement but its not working

Comment: {% for item in customer %}
  {{post}} - 
  {{item.customer_id}} <br>
     {% if post == item.customer_id %}
   test

Answer (score 0):

As @Daniel told that, You need to add name field to select tag not for option tag,

```
<select name='customer_id'>
        {% for item in customer %}
        <option value={{ item.customer_id }} >{{ item.customer_name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type = 'submit' value='Edit'>
        </select>
```

Comment: i did that i have a new question @dhana please look at them and see waht you think

Comment: just do this `selected_customer_id = request.POST["customer_id"]`